# Error "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto." en vb

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, vb.net

Soy algo nuevo en VB, ya lo revise y no veo algún detalle, tal vez estoy dejando pasar algo pero no se que es.
Al momento de ejecutar el programa, arroja un error de referencia a objeto no establecida.

Este es mi código:

```
Public Sub btnSaveSaldoFavor_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveSaldoFavor.Click
    Try
        If txtObservacionSaldoFavor.Text = "" Or txtSaldoFavor.Text = "" Then
            MuestraMensaje("El Campo Observacion No Puede Estar Vacio", "Error", "Error")

        ElseIf MessageBox.Show("¿Sus datos son correctos?", "Agregar", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim Saldo As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(txtSaldoFavor.Text())
            Dim Observacion As String = txtObservacionSaldoFavor.Text()

            Dim Res As Integer = InsertaSaldosAFavor(1, _IdCliente, Saldo, _FolioOperacion, Observacion)
            MessageBox.Show("Registro Generado con Exito", "Exito")
            Me.Close()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MuestraMensaje("Error al Agregar el registro: " & ex.Message, String.Empty, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub

Imports System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Module mdlInsertSaldosAFavor
Private InsertCommand As SqlCommand
Private SqlConSaldos As SqlConnection

Public Function InsertaSaldosAFavor(Accion As Integer, fiIdCliente As Integer, fnSaldo 
As Decimal, _
                                      fvFolio As String, fvObservacion As String) As 
Integer
    Dim Res As Integer = 0

    Try
        ''Dim SqlConSaldos As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Saldos_A_Favor").ConnectionString)
        InsertCommand = New SqlCommand("SP_SaldosAFavorManager", SqlConSaldos)
        InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Accion", Accion)
        InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fiIdCliente", fiIdCliente)
        InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fnSaldo", fnSaldo)
        InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fvFolio", fvFolio)
        InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fvObservacion", fvObservacion)

        SqlConSaldos.Open()

        Res = InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        SqlConSaldos.Close()
        SqlConSaldos.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Error,Al Insertar Saldo A Favor" & ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return Res
End Function
End Module
```

El error aparece en la linea comentada:

```
Dim SqlConSaldos As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Saldos_A_Favor").ConnectionString)
```

Comment: Saludos. Verifica que cada instrucción tenga un valor que no sea `Nothing` o `Null` (o cualquier otro) para los datos requeridos. Por lo regular es cuando una variable no es inicializada, solo está declarada.

Comment: Para esto generé un nuevo archivo.config ¿Es posible que por ese motivo sea el error? Saludos....

Comment: De ser así ¿Cómo puedo referenciar ese nuevo archivo.config a mi modulo?

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. te sugiero un breakpoint antes de `new` donde se genera el error; e inspecciones el valor de `New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Saldos_A_Favor").ConnectionString)` si esto falla o devuleve `Nothing` o `Null` entonces inspecciona `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Saldos_A_Favor").ConnectionString` si este falla pues inspeccionar `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Saldos_A_Favor")` y así hacia atrás; para que verifiques el valor esperado es el que se está leyendo de tu config.